# c++ passing std::function with custom object as argument in threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, function

I have an seperate class to handle threading, and there is a function need to create a thread and repeat the function for a specific interval

```
void timer_start_custom(std::function<void(string, string&, vector<CustomObject>&)> func, string filename, string& lastline, vector<CustomObject>& dict, unsigned int interval){
     std::thread([func, interval, filename, lastline, dict](){
         while (true){
             auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
             func(filename, lastline, dict);
             std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
         }
     }).detach();
}
```

however, right now the compiler compain :

```
No matching function for call to object of type 'const
std::function<void (string, string &, vector<RowData> &)>' (aka
'const function<void (basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >,
basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > &, vector<RowData> &)>')
```

I know if a place the function in the same file, then i can skip the func as parameter, but i am still very curious and stubborn to know how to work this out, as i will call the `timer_start_custom` in different file and pass in different functions

Comment: Indent your code.-

Comment: What is the reason for passing `lastline` and `dict` by non-const reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are capturing `lastline` and `dict` by-value and then passing them to the `func` which expect non-const references. You probably need to capture like this instead:

```
std::thread([func, interval, filename, &lastline, &dict] {
...
});
```

However you should be especially careful when capturing by-reference to make sure that those object are still alive when they are used in lambda, especially given that you are calling it in a separate thread. This also creates a possibility of a data race, so if you are going to access `lastline` and `dict` from several threads you need to make sure to use proper synchronization mechanisms such as `std::mutex`.

Comment: @PaulSanders 

Comment: Sorry about the pointless edit - I thought I was editing my own answer.  Time for some sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Capturing variables by value makes them implicitly `const` in the body of the lambda, which is why passing them to `func` as non-cost references fails to compile.

You can therefore either do what r3mus n0x recommends in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55443796/560648), or pass them to `func` by value or as `const ref`.  I think I prefer r3mus n0x's solution as it involves fewer temporaries, provided that the variables referred to don't go out of scope while the thread is executing..

Comment: Fewer temporaries in what way?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, making a copy of `dict`, for example, might be expensive.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Oh yes, passing by value would be bad.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes.  I posted an answer, mainly, to explain why the original code doesn't compile.